# MarkLogic Failover Cluster on Azure - Forest configuration on Azure Blob

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, marklogic, failover, azure-blob-storage

As per MarkLogic cluster recommendation, we need to configure it as per below link

[MarkLogic Cluster - Configure Forest with all documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964039/marklogic-cluster-configure-forest-with-all-documents)

Forest configuration is done as per [MarkLogic on Azure Guide Page No. 28](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/azure.pdf) i.e.

- Azure storage key has been set in Security -> Credentials -> Azure
- Data directory has been set as azure://

This is working fine and every forest on cluster host has been set in a different container within same azure Blob.

Now i want to configure failover cluster by replicating forest of each host on different host as per failover configuration mentioned in above link.

Question: In documentation, it is mentioned that "only local disk failover is possible", if i create replication forest same as data forest i.e. mentioning azure container will work ?

Data directory for Master forests are configured on Azure blob only and ingestion performance was also good compared to local disk or map azure blob as local drive on VM

[image]

[image]
[image]

I created replica forest and mapped it to Azure Blob and started getting below error and label size in Azure blob size got to 0 and master forest label size also got to 0 and i lost all data :( (BTW, it is dev environment)

[image]
Forest-id01 - Host01

Forest-id02 - Host02

Forest-id03 - Host03

Forest-id01-replica - Host02

Forest-id02-replica - Host03

Forest-id03-replica - Host01

All are in one Azure Blob (as in security->credentials, we can only provide one storage account) in different containers

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As Ganesh mentioned in his answer, this is an unsupported configuration...Blob storage does not support the IOps necessary for a production system.  Since you've elminated the hosts names, can you put the attempted mapping in the question (e.g. forest-id02 is on host2, forest-id02-replica is on host3, etc).  Since it's a single container, it appears that the labels may be trying to overwrite each other.  You may need to find a way to separate the forests (folders?) in the Blob.

Comment: Hello Michael, Thanks for your reply, Added related info, can you please check if this is supported configuration? BtW, i do not have any issues during ingestion, issues happens when i add replica forest to master forest

Comment: No matter what changes you make, unless the Forest data is mounted to Standard or Premium level storage, it will not be supported.  That doesn't mean it won't work, just that you are on your own if you run into issues.

Comment: Thank Michale for your reply. Understood. So to get support we need to use Azure Manage Disks i.e. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/managed-disks. Fine. Is it possible to update MarkLogic documentation accordingly, as it is not very clear that if we use how it is mentioned (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/azure.pdf, Page No.28) then it will not be supported somewhere here (http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/azure/GettingStarted) ?  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic does not support regular or replica forest on Azure blob storage. MarkLogic does not write labels on Azue blob storage, which is the error you are getting. We support Azure blob storage for backup and read-only forest for Tiered storage feature. Apologies for the wrong answer before

Comment: OK, but configuring data directory of forest on Azure Blob works fine (as mentioned above link) and all data writes as expected in Azure Blob with labels. As soon as i create replica forest and configured in master forest, label size goes to zero,

Comment: Added more info in question to make sure that regular forest data directory configuration works fine with Azure Blob storage as mentioned in Page No. 28, problem is only when replica is created and configured in master forest, label size became zero i.e. all forest related information is lost